# Show an existing div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to enhance my forum software a bit. Lets say I have an div with the ID: 123.

Now someone replies to this div and quotes it. I want to show this div if someone hovers over the quote.

I tried this so far but no success.

```
$(".referal").hover(function() {
    var id_post = $(this).attr('id')
    $('#reply_' + id_post).show();
});
```

It gets the right ID but somehow only gets executed if I paste it in the console. The existing div also won't be displayed a second time near the quote.

Am I  mistaken the show event somehow? I tried with .clone before but also no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
Handle post number as a global id:

```
var id_post;
$(".referal").hover(function() {
    id_post = $(this).attr('id')
    $('#reply_' + id_post).show();    
});

$(".referal").on("mouseout",function() {
    $('#reply_'+id_post).hide();
});
```

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0vjkxz9y/4/

This is a working example of what you want to do:

```
$('#reply_5').hide();
$(".referal").hover(function() {
    var id_post = $(this).attr('id')
    $('#reply_' + id_post).show();
});

$(".referal").on("mouseout",function() {
    $('#reply_5').hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0vjkxz9y/

Comment: This is good, except the mouseout only handles #reply_5, not any of the possible replies. There should be a class called replies that hides ALL of them on mouseout,

Comment: You are absolutely correct. This only hides that particular reply as an example, we can save the id_post on hover and use that same value on mouseout, if we really need to.

Comment: I like this answer, to finalize it: I **THINK** you could use `'$('div[id^="reply_"]').hide()` .. But not tested.. This should hide all div's with id prefix `reply_` .. EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/0vjkxz9y/17/ Tested working

Comment: It is a nice safeguard call to do that, but if you are careful enough you shouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `toggleClass` ?

```js
$( ".referal" ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", function( event ) {
  var id_post = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#reply_' + id_post).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.test {
    display: none;
}
.test.active{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="referal" id="123">This div has ID 123</div>
<div class="test" id="reply_123">This div has ID reply_123</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(".referal").hover(function() {
  var id_post = $(this).attr('id')
  $('#reply_'+ id_post +'').show();
});
```

Comment: There is no need to concat the end .. Have you tested this ?